# Python: reading integers from a file

Tags: python

I have a file with an integer in every new line. No line contains two integers. How can I read integers one by one while omitting "new line" symbols, so I can calculate the sum of all integers? I must NOT use list.

Comment: When reading from files, it reads line by line so you can use .chomp to remove the new lines and you can use int() to make the the stringed number into a proper int. Also, you may want to try: except ValueError: in case you can't intify the string

Comment: @ATLUS ... did you just say `chomp`? o_O

Comment: I made a mistake, I was thinking of Ruby which has chomp. You can use .rstrip in Python to remove trailing newline tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just loop over your file line by line like so

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    total=0
    for i in f:
        total+=int(i)
    print total
```

alternatively you can condense this into a list comprehension and use `sum()`

```
print sum([int(i) for i in f])
```

Comment: Not sure what the OP means with *"must NOT use list"*, but your second solution does use a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    print(sum(map(int, f)))
```

Comment: I up voted. That's a cool answer, I didn't know you could do it that way

Comment: @SirParselot Good, raising awareness for that was a goal. I'm also pleasantly surprised that nobody posted an `f.readlines()` solution :-)

Comment: I don't think an `f.readlines()` solution would be as elegant since you would have to strip the new lines

Comment: @SirParselot No, you wouldn't have to, as `int` ignores them. That's also why our solutions work. The way we're reading the file, we also get the newlines. The real issue with `readlines` is that it's pointless and wasteful and ugly. And if the OP's *"must NOT use list"* is meant as *"must not use A list"*, then it's also **wrong**, as `readlines` does create a list.